# Regex string for IRC

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex string to match a string revived from an IRC channel.

The message will be in the format "!COMMAND parameters"; the only command that is built by the system so far is repeat.

The regex I am using looks like this:

```
/![repeat] (.*?)/
```

When other commands are added it will look like:

```
/![cmd1|cmd2|cmd3] (.*?)/
```

It does not seem to be matching the right things in the string.  Can anyone offer any input on this?

It appears that I need to add some basic regex stuff.

() brackets return data, [] matches but does not return.

Swapping to () does not work either.

The IRC program I am writing has a dynamic number of commands, so far I have only added "repeat" so the command pattern is "[repeat]".  If I added "say", it would be "[repeat|say]".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the parentheses for grouping:

```
/!(cmd1|cmd2|cmd3) (.*)/
```

The brackets `[…]` denote a character class describing just one character out of a set of characters.

You should also not use a non-greedy `.*` as the minimal match of `.*?` is an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing one thing wrong.
If you replace your `[]` brackets with `()` everything should work. Between `[]` you put some letters to match.  `[abc]` would match a, b, or c, not "abc", while `(abc)` would match "abc" and `(abc|bca)` would match "abc" or "bca".

Check out the Perl regular expressions [tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) and [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You used bad brackets

```
/!(cmd1|cmd2|cmd3) (.*)/
```

I don't understand what did you mean with `?` in your regex

Comment: The `?` makes the match non greedy.

Answer (score 1):

`[repeat]` is a character class and will match r or e or p etc..., you should just use

```
/!repeat (.*?)/
```

and

```
/!(cmd1|cmd2|cmd3) (.*?)/
```

I don't understand exactly what you are hoping to match, but the lazy operator seems wrong for example

`/!COMMAND (.*?)/` applied to `!COMMAND paramater` will match `!COMMAND` only, `(.*?)` at the end of a regex is guaranteed to match nothing.